# Using 9patch background makes text invisible in EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I use a transparent 9patch image as a background in EditText and after that, no text inside EditText is visible. When I remove background, everything goes OK. Any idea?

This is 9patch image:

[image]

And this is EditText:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/areaEditText"
    style="@style/EditText"
/>

<style name="EditText">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">48dip</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/edit_text_bg</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">5dip</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">5dip</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">10dip</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_dark</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Perhaps the font color is the same as the background color of whatever is behind the `EditText`.

Comment: Background is white and textColor is black

Comment: Post your 9-patch image here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]check your fill area on 9patch, suppose it's wrong

Comment: fill area is transparent.

Comment: can you please share you 9patch I want to check it

Comment: try picture, which i've posted

Comment: I think your text view is not wide enough for the text amount you entered there

Answer (score 1):

I compared my 9patch with Android's in android sdk. I changed my 9patch and everything goes OK.

This is WRONG patch:

[image]

And this is CORRECT:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you should not make a transparent background image, you can use a background color like this `<TextView
   ...
   android:background="#CCFF0000" />`

Please test it and tell me if it work in your case